# Почему Ruby выкидывает ошибку при запуске файла?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Почему Ruby выкидывает ошибку при запуске файла? Устанавливал RailsInstaller. Раньше все было нормально. Плюс к этому файлу даю разрешение rb, а он видит как блокнот

В чем проблема?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Имена файлов с пробелами - это обычно боль. Переименуйте файл или вызывайте правильно.

```
ruby "hello world.rb"
```